# Is it possible to run Shiny as a subprocess of a main app?

Tags: r, multithreading, shiny, server

I'm facing the usual problem of scaling a computational-intense shiny app to multiple non-blocking users.

I am aware of promises for outsourcing intense computations, but I'd like single-user operations to be synchronous (so as to easily add progress bars for long computations), while each user is independent from each other. That is, an independent process per user session, not per operation.

So my idea was to use a main shiny server (or other R server) to spawn independent child processes for each user, each with her own shiny app which then send back the results to the front end.

Do you have any guidance on this?

Comment: You might want to check [library(callr)](https://github.com/r-lib/callr) and it's function `r_bg()`.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw your previous comment. My problem is that I'd like the entire shiny app to run on a different subprocess for each user, while I don't need async works inside the user session (he/she can wait). I wouldn't know how to spawn a whole shiny infrastructure, with IO from the browser, etc in a different process with callr. These processes should stay alive and interact with the user until she closes the browser window. How would this be possible with callr?

Comment: To be honest I still think promises are your best choice here, as this is shiny's official async backend and they are aiming at [inter-session responsiveness](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23#issuecomment-386687705). Please also check `AsyncProgress` from [library(ipc)](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html)

Comment: uhm, my question is exactly how to enclose the whole app in a async promise, not just pieces of it.

Comment: I understood that - this however isn't the intended way to make use of promises in shiny and I guess if you try to realize it there will be a lot of difficulties. As an alternative you could wrap your app in a docker container and scale it downstream: https://shinyproxy.io/documentation/configuration/#kubernetes